# Выбор оптимального запроса (PHP и MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго вам времени суток! Даже не знаю, как сформулировать свой вопрос, начну с начала.

На странице будут храниться "теги-позиции", их количество не известно до того, как их не соберёт регулярка, а после нужно будет отправить запросы к базе данных для получения данных полей, в качестве ключей полей используются названия "тегов-позиций". Понимаю, что голословно объясняюсь, вот пример:

Страница, текст которой разбираем на "теги-позиции"

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>$TITLE$</div>
<div>$MENU$</div>
<div>$CONTENT$</div>
<div>$BOTTOM_MENU$</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Регулярка вернула нам массив из 4-х значений :

```
0 - $TITLE$
1 - $MENU$
2 - $CONTENT$
3 - $BOTTOM_MENU$
```

В базе хранятся записи для таких тегов :

```
key - tag - value
1 - $HEADER$ - </>
2 - $TITLE$ - ololo
3 - $MENU$ - menu123
4 - $CONTENT$ - cnt
5 - $BOTTOM_MENU$ - btm menu
6 - $IF_ERROR$ - error
7 - $IF_LOGIN_TRUE$ - u r loginned
8 -......
9 -......
```

И теперь нужно для каждого тега получить значение из базы, и собственно передо мною стоит проблема, с одной стороны 4 запроса к базе это много, т.к. нужно выбрать подходящие (WHERE tag='$tag'), если получить значения всех строк из базы в массив, то это тоже не логично ибо.

**`$sql_get_tag = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM menus WHERE tag='$tag'");` // вариант с 4-мя запросами**

**`$sql_get_tags = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM menus");` // вариант с запросом всех строк**

Как мне быть, какой вариант выбрать, дайте совет, подскажите свой вариант, т.к. тегов на странице и данных в базе может быть от одного до 20-и.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `value` FROM `menus` WHERE `tag` IN ( "'.implode('", "', $arr).'" )';
```

Где `$arr` это результат регулярки.

Для

```
0 - $TITLE$
1 - $MENU$
2 - $CONTENT$
3 - $BOTTOM_MENU$
```

Получим

```
$sql = 'SELECT `value` FROM `menus` WHERE `tag` IN ( "$TITLE$", "$MENU$", "$CONTENT$", "$BOTTOM_MENU$" )';
```

Comment: +) А чем отличается этот способ от обычного WHERE +or?

Comment: Это один запрос, создающийся автоматически по **любое** кол-во найденных тегов<br>
По скорости - врятле есть существенное отличие

Comment: Ну, да, поудобнее) Всегда теперь буду пользоваться в таких ситуациях, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, 1 запрос к MySQL будет лучше. Нагрузка меньше. Я бы сделал так:

```
$sql_get_tags = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM menus WHERE tag='$tag[0]' or tag='$tag[1]' or tag='$tag[2]' or tag='$tag[3]'");
```